# Symfony 2 ACL and Role Hierarchy

Tags: php, symfony, acl, hierarchy, roles

I'm a little stuck and unable to find the answer to this.

In my app test I've created two Entities User and Comment both are mapped correctly.

I have created a small controller which depending on the user will add the comment and the data to the **ACL** tables, if I create my comment as a standard user with the associated for of 'ROLE_USER', and Try to access it as user with the role 'ROLE_ADMIN' I get access denied, it seems to completely ignore the security.yml hierarchy.

I know this works by adding instead of the userid the ROLE_USER etc but I don't want to do it this way.

Examples of my code are below.

**CommentController**

```
    <?php

    namespace ACL\TestBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use ACL\TestBundle\Forms\Type\commentType;
    use ACL\TestBundle\Entity\Comment;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\ObjectIdentity;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\UserSecurityIdentity;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder;

    class DefaultController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * @Route("/", name="_default")
         * @Template()
         */
        public function indexAction()
        {
            die('success');
        }

        /**
         * @Route("/comment/new/")
         * @Template()
         */
        public function newAction(Request $request)
        {
            $comment = new Comment();

            $form = $this->createForm(new commentType(), $comment);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $comment->setUsers($this->getUser());
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($comment);
                $em->flush();

                // creating the ACL
                $aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
                $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($comment);
                $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

                // retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
                $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($this->getUser());

                // grant owner access
                $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
                $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
            }

            return array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            );
        }

        /**
         * @Route("/comment/{id}/", requirements={"id":"\d+"})
         * @Template()
         */
        public function editAction(Request $request,$id)
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $comment = $em->find('ACLTestBundle:Comment', $id);

            $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');

            // check for edit access
            if (false === $securityContext->isGranted('EDIT',$comment)) {
                throw new AccessDeniedException();
            }

            $form = $this->createForm(new commentType(), $comment);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if($form->isValid()){
                $em->persist($comment);
                $em->flush();
            }

            return array('form' => $form->createView());
        }
    }
```

**security.yml**

```
 security:
        encoders:
            ACL\TestBundle\Entity\User: plaintext
        acl:
            connection: default

        providers:
            database:
                entity: { class: ACLTestBundle:User }

        role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

        firewalls:
            dev:
                pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
                security: false
            main:
                pattern:     ^/
                provider:    database
                anonymous:   true
                logout:      true
                switch_user: true
                form_login:
                    login_path: _security_login

        access_control:
            - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: This line (`$securityContext->isGranted('EDIT',$comment)`) seems a little strange to me. I usually see that call only with roles, where does `EDIT` come from, where is it set? And what happens if you check the role there?

Comment: @nietonfir The question is about ACL and role hierarchy, so this is not a duplicate. `EDIT` mask is a part of `OWNER` mask, which is set to the entity on create.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding adding ACL base on UserIdentity and want to check the gran base on RoleIdentity. If you want to do it Role base change the creating ACL as below

```
// creating the ACL
$aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
$objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($comment);
$acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

// retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
$securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($this->getUser());

// grant owner access
$acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);

// grant EDIT access to ROLE_ADMIN
$securityIdentity = new RoleSecurityIdentity('ROLE_ADMIN');
$acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_EDIT);
$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

As you see I kept the owner access for the specific user then I added Edit access for ROLE_ADMIN. You can keep the controller as is.

If you don't want to make it Role base but just want to give an exception for admin users you can change your controller as

```
// check for edit access
if (false === $securityContext->isGranted('EDIT',$comment) && false === $securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN') ) {
   throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

Comment: So does that mean that ACL doesn't support `role_hierarchy`?

Comment: @VisioN It does, but you are assigning ACL to the object User base not Role base, then how can you check if it's granted for specific Role? Take a look at this hopefully will get the concept of Role base User base [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html#security-identities] It says **Each role, or user has its own security identity.**

Comment: To my personal concern, if a `ROLE_USER` account has access to an *entity* and `ROLE_ADMIN` by `role_hierarchy` contains `ROLE_USER`, he should automatically get access to all *entities*, so you don't need to add `RoleSecurityIdentity` for him manually. Doesn't that make sense? Could you please provide an example of how ACL supports `role_hierarchy`, as I honestly don't see any possible way of making `ROLE_ADMIN` to have access to `ROLE_USER`-managed entities without inserting separate `RoleSecurityIdentity` or hardcoding `isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')` in the controller.

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve, is this possible?

Comment: @VisioN It's totally true, if a user has `ROLE_USER` and **if all the entity objects are granted to this role** then `ROLE_ADMIN` will inherit that will have access. The problem in this case is he is assigning the MASK to UserIdentity not a Role and is checking base on that UserIdentity (`$securityContext->isGranted('EDIT',$comment)`) Now how can you make sure that User X with ROLE_ADMIN has grant to `$comment`. That's why Symfony separated ACL process to ROLE base or USER base, and it says **Each role, or user has its own security identity.**

Comment: That's why I added MASK_EDIT for ROLE_ADMIN so that all admin users (either X or Y or ...) have edit access. I can suggest to read this section of Documentation and hopefully it helps [http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#complex-access-controls-with-expressions]. I will try to provide a full ACL example if I get a chance; Maybe this link could be a full example of ACL in different Scopes [http://rryter.blogspot.ca/2012/02/symfony2-and-acls.html]

Comment: @VisioN You're welcome, sorry if I could not explain perfectly

Comment: Cheers guys, decision made